# Mean curvature on a Torus

Tags: differential-geometry

So we have learned that on a Torus in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ we can find points where the Gaussian Curvature $K$, can be $K>0$, $K<0$ and also $K=0$. Now I have  a question where I have to answer if there are points on this Torus where mean curvature $H$ is $H=0$.

So at first impact i would say yes there might be but there don't have to be.
$K$ is defined  as $K=k_{1}*k_{2}$. In the points where $K$ is $0$ it can happen that $H=0$ and also in the points where $K<0$ it can happen that $H=0$ if $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$
are inverses of each other.
But of course it doesn't have to be like this, $K$ can be as  it is on a Torus and nevertheless there might happen the case where  $H$ is not $0$.

Would this argument be alright?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This highly depends on which torus you are talking about. An embedded "round" torus in $\mathbb{R}^2$ depends on two parameters, the radii of the two circles in the parametrization. Depending on the ratio of these radii, the mean curvature may be positive everywhere or not.

Comment: Did you write down (compute) the principal curvatures and write down (compute) the mean curvature? This is not an abstract consideration.